# IllegalStateExceptionget field slot from row 0 col 0 failed even though moveToFirst() was true

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor

This is the relevant piece of code:

```
77: Cursor lastDateCursor = db.query(tableName, new String[] {
78:               "MAX(start)"
79: }, null, null, null, null, null); 
80: if (lastDateCursor != null && lastDateCursor.moveToFirst()) {
81:     lastDate = UtilsApp.convertDateToEpoch(lastDateCursor.getString(0), mContext);
.....
```

And I get the following exception:

> IllegalStateExceptionget field slot from row 0 col 0 failed on line 81.

Can anyone explain why line 81 was reached, if the query didn't return any results (i.e. why was moveToFirst() true)? Or could there be an alternative explanation for the exception?

Edited to add:
The Android documentation on Cursor.moveToFirst() (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29) states, that:

> This method will return false if the cursor is empty.

Answer (score 0):

test the cursor like this

if(lastDateCursor != null && lastDateCursorgetCount()>0){
  }

Comment: Thank you, I will also check for getCount()>0. However, based on the documentation, moveToFirst() should also return false, if count is 0: "This method will return false if the cursor is empty." [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29). Also, I think that !=null is superfluous, as the query will always return at leat an empty cursor.